# How avoid duplicate test in junit?

Tags: junit, integration-testing, spring-test

I have two entity isv and app.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `isv` (
`id` int primary key,
`code` varchar(128) not null
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `app` (
`id` int primary key,
`isv_code` varchar(128) not null,
`code` varchar(128) not null
);
```

I add two controller: IsvController::createIsv and AppController::createApp.

Now, I need add unit test.

IsvControllerTest::createIsvTest build isv and call IsvController::createIsv by mockmvc, then I add @Rollback will auto clear dirty data.
IsvControllerTest.java

```java
    @Transactional
    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void createIsv() throws Exception {
        IsvCreateDTO isvCreateDTO = IsvDataBuilder.isvCreateDTO();
        String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(isvCreateDTO);
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/isvs").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(body);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
        Result<String> result = objectMapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Result.class);
        assertTrue(result.getCode() == 0 && result.getResult().equals(isvCreateDTO.getCode()));
    }
```

AppControllerTest::createApp need test create app, But app need existed isv_code. So I will first create a isv, but it is same as IsvControllerTest::createIsvTest.
AppControllerTest.java

```java
    @Transactional
    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void createApp() throws Exception {
        IsvCreateDTO isvCreateDTO = IsvDataBuilder.isvCreateDTO();
        String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(isvCreateDTO);
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/isvs").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(body);
        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
        Result<String> result = objectMapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Result.class);
        assertTrue(result.getCode() == 0 && result.getResult().equals(isvCreateDTO.getCode()));


        AppCreateDTO appCreateDTO = AppDataBuilder.appCreateDTO();
        body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(appCreateDTO);
        request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/apps").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(body).header("isvCode", isvCreateDTO.getCode()); // <<<<< Notice !!!
        mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
        result = objectMapper.readValue(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Result.class);
        assertTrue(result.getCode() == 0 && result.getResult().equals(appCreateDTO.getCode()));
    }
```

How can I organize better unit test to avoid duplicate create isv?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be specific without seeing any of your code. In general terms I would suggest to create a base class for your test classes that contains common setup code.

Edit: Apparently this is not about duplication of setup code. Your tests are integration tests which are usually slow and have complicated setups. In your specific case I would put all of this in one test case. First test the creation of the isv and then in the same test case test the creation of the app. This is actually what your `createApp()` test case is already doing.

Comment: So, should I put createIsvTest to createAppTest and delete createIsvTest?

Comment: `createApp` already contains all of `createIsv`. Just get rid of `createIsv`.